# Installing Drupal on Fedora 29 Live USB

Tags: apache, web, drupal, server, fedora

I followed this guide: https://fedoramagazine.org/howto-install-drupal-8-fedora/

Everything went well except that when I try to pull up the web page at localhost I get the apache welcome page.

I tried following the instructions (comment everything out) to not use the welcome page, renaming the welcome.conf to ~welcome.conf. Neither worked.

I'm sure it's something simple. I had the same issue trying to install Wordpress.